# load more button in android listview not working/triggered

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to display a list of comments with a "load more" button. But somehow my button is not triggered. It seems the listener doesn't do anything... 
Here is my code:

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listComments;
private String FullJson = "";
private static int current_page = 0;
private int offset = 0;

public int getOffset() {
    return current_page * 10;
}

private ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
protected String qid = "", udida="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

    listComments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listComments);
    //get list of comments on this question
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    qid = intent.getStringExtra(QuestionActivity.EXTRA_QID);
    udida = intent.getStringExtra(QuestionActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    FullJson = intent.getStringExtra(QuestionActivity.EXTRA_JSON);
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://heycrowd.com/requests/questionWithComments.json?questionId="+qid+"&offset="+getOffset());

    // LoadMore button
    Button btnLoadMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load_more);;

    //Listening to Load More button click event
    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Starting a new async task
            new GetIdTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

public String getIdThread () {
    try {
        Context ctx = CommentActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
        AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(ctx);
        final String id = adInfo.getId();
        return id;

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        return "Error 1";

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Error 2";
        // Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g.,
        // the old version of the service doesn't support getting AdvertisingId).

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        return"Error 3";
        // Google Play services is not available entirely.
    }
}
private class GetIdTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CommentActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return getIdThread();
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://heycrowd.com/requests/questionWithComments.json?questionId="+qid+"&offset="+getOffset());

        // closing progress dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private List<HashMap<String,String>> getListItems(JSONArray FullJson) {
    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0; i< FullJson.length() ;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        try {

            hm.put("text", FullJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
            hm.put("date", FullJson.getJSONObject(i).getString("created_at"));

            //get user (picture + name)
            JSONObject userObj = FullJson.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("user");
            hm.put("user_id", userObj.getString("user_id"));
            hm.put("user_name", userObj.getString("name"));
            hm.put("user_img",userObj.getString("image_url"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            //some exception handler code.
        }

        aList.add(hm);
    }

    return aList;
}

private void populateListView(JSONArray FullJson) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = getListItems(FullJson);

    ListView listCommentView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listComments);
    int currentPosition = listCommentView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    CommentAdapter adapter =new CommentAdapter(this, aList );

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listCommentView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Setting new scroll position
    listCommentView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

    //get logged user's image (at the moment, default image)
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.getApplicationContext());
    ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.me_img);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}


private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Utils.GET(urls[0]);
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray commentsArr = json.getJSONObject("question").getJSONArray("comments"); // get comments array

            populateListView(commentsArr);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //some exception handler code.
        }

    }
}
```

}

So when I get for the first time on my page, i get the first 10 comments, but when I click on my "load more" button: nothing happens.
I've set a point break on getIdTask() witch is supposed to be called on the click event, and I never get there. I can't seem to find why my button is not reacting to anything.
Also, I thought maybe calling several times an AsyncTask may be the problem, but I tried on the "OnCreate" to get the first 10 lines without an Asynctask, and then nothing worked anymore...
I'm stuck on this since yesterday, pls help!

I'm adding also the layout XML just in case:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Load more comments"
        android:id="@+id/load_more"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listComments"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/me_img"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:contentDescription="user"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:lines="5"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: how many asynctask you are using in your code! why this much of rotations in code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood why my onclick listener was not working/triggered at all, it took me some time :-(
I have this code inside my populateListView method (first line)

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);
```

I removed it and it made all by listeners work again...
Probably this confused something here, to be honest i don't really understand :-(